# Passing Activity A's data into Activity B

Tags: android

What i am trying to show here is that I am trying to pass the data in Activity A to Activity B. Activity A mainly there are 3 textbox for me to key in something then a button to go to Activity B(Confirmation Page) and in Activity B, i am able to show what i have keyed in Activity A. I am new to Android, so can someone guide me through this?

**In Activity A**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitya);

    Textview01 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    Textview02 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
    Textview03 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView3);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class); 
            i.putExtra("Textview01", txtView1.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("Textview02", txtView2.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("Textview03", txtView3.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
```

**In Activity B.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.confirmbooking);

    TextView txtPickup = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtPickup);
    TextView txtLocation = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
    TextView txtDestination = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtDestination);

    txtLocation.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Location"));
    txtPickup.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Pick Up Point"));
    txtDestination.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Destination"));
```

In my Activity B XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="txtView01:" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtView01"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="txtView02:"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtView02"></TextView>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="txtView03:"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtView03"></TextView>

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Book now" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell me if this is correct? I'm getting some error like a popup Instrumental.class.

LogCat shows :

```
11-26 17:27:40.895: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=ActivityA/.ActivityB (has extras) }
    11-26 17:27:42.956: DEBUG/dalvikvm(252): GC_EXPLICIT freed 156 objects / 11384 bytes in 346ms
    11-26 17:27:47.815: DEBUG/dalvikvm(288): GC_EXPLICIT freed 31 objects / 1496 bytes in 161ms
```

Comment: Next time search so many of these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

**A**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activitya);

EditText  Textview01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
EditText  Textview02 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
EditText  Textview03 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView3);

Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class); 
        i.putExtra("Textview01", Textview01 .getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("Textview02", Textview02 .getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("Textview03", Textview03 .getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
```

**B**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityb);

    TextView txtView01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView01);
    TextView txtView02 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView02);
    TextView txtView03 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView03);

    String s1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01");
    String s2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview02");
    String s3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview03");

    txtView01.setText(s1);
    txtView02.setText(s2);
    txtView03.setText(s3);
```

Comment: in Activity B, those txtView01 and s1 and co are unuse.

Comment: if u want to set those text to text view, see my answer now

Comment: Why in Activity A, we need to set this ? TextView  Textview01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView1);

Comment: Can't, i keep getting this popup class called Instrumentation.Class

Comment: post log cat what you are getting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5367/discussion-between-polamreddyrajareddy-and-user1058153)

Comment: Polam, what if it's an integer not string?

Comment: same procedure , at receiver end  my_size = i.getIntExtra("size",20); use this.

Answer (score 0):

First you do:

```
txtView01 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView01);
```

then you redeclare this variable:

```
String txtView01 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01");
```

This is an error that should stop you from even trying it. I surmise you forgot to show some code, like; prior the String declaration, where's `txtView01` declared, and how?

Comment: declared in XML ? Can you show me how to? Because i'm kind of new to android.

Comment: What you want to do is probably `txtView01.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01"));` after the `findViewById()`.

Comment: If you want any help you will have to provide the full backtrace for the error. A single line is impossible to trouble-shoot.

Comment: Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1406 
Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1380

Comment: There isn't any error, it just a pop up class called Instrumentation.class

Answer (score 0):

Create a vaiable of type Button.Then implement onClickListener.

```
Button bt1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

or

Change the variable names given to all strings in Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

You have done like

```
 txtView01 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView01);
        txtView02 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView02);
        txtView03 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtView03);
```

and then assigning text to TextView so you are getting the problem

You need to make 3 String variables and assign into it,

like String str1,str2,str3..

```
str1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview01");
str2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview02");
str3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Textview03");
```

and then set Text to TextView 
like,

```
txtView01.setText(str1);
```